# Error - There is no row at position 0 C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

When I debug my project, I get this error:

There is no row at position 0

[image]

Code Error in return (byte[]) ...

```
public static Byte[] BaixarArquivo(long codArquivo)
        {
            Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
            DBCommandWrapper dbCommandWrapper = db.GetStoredProcCommandWrapper("GERREL_ARQUIVO_BAIXAR");
            dbCommandWrapper.AddInParameter("@CODARQUIVO" , DbType.Int32 , codArquivo);

            >>>> return (byte[]) db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommandWrapper).Tables[0].Rows[0]["ARQUIVO"];
        }
```

I checked the database and found no problems. what might be happening?

=====

```
private void Page_Load (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
String codigoArquivo = Request.QueryString ["CodArquivo"];
Response.BinaryWrite (BO.Arquivo.BaixarArquivo (int.Parse (codigoArquivo)));

}
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure you have data in your db? Not only structure

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory. Your Table[0] has no rows. If you don't know why, debug it.

Comment: check if `db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommandWrapper).Tables[0]` returns something - add it f.e. to watch in VS. If not - you don't  event have the table

Comment: What is happening is you are not getting any rows back.

Comment: Have you tested your query on the db end? does it return any rows?

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteDataSet` seems to return a `DataSet` which contains a table that is empty. So you have to check if it's correct that no rows were returned from the stored-procedure.

If it's possible check the `Rows.Count`:

```
var ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommandWrapper);
if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
     return null;
else
    return (byte[]) ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ARQUIVO"];
```

Otherwise you have to fix the sql in the SP.

Comment: Better to check `ds .Tables.Count` as well??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: if the `DataSet` contains no tables that is a serious bug in `ExecuteDataSet` that has to be fixed. So returning `null` would be wrong in that case.

Comment: Never used this, just checking :)

Comment: Isn't ExecuteDataSet outdated and Microsoft want us to use DataReader or DataAdapter ?

Comment: @MeAndSomeRandoms: Looks like, it says [This content is outdated and is no longer being maintained](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data.database.executedataset.aspx)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: just noticed that it's the enterprise library `ExecuteDataSet`. So i've also haven't used it before. But i doubt that the method can return an empty DataSet with no tables if you have to provide a sql command.

Comment: I did the solution you suggested in debug it goes to this function Tim 

private void Page_Load (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
String codigoArquivo = Request.QueryString ["CodArquivo"];
Response.BinaryWrite (BO.Arquivo.BaixarArquivo (int.Parse (codigoArquivo)));

}

an exception is generated in Reponse.Binary ...

checked all the data is there on the table